# How to reset Asp.Net Core Response.Body after writing some data

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to reset Response.Body after writing some data in the Middleware for some reasons.

What I have tried in Middleware Invoke method:

```
if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
{
    // Not committed / data was not sent to client yet

    // Reset Response
    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
    context.Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = null;

    if (context.Response.Body.CanSeek)
    {
        context.Response.Body.SetLength(0);
    }

    // Reset headers
    responseWrapper.ResetAddedHeaders()
}
```

**The issue is context.Response.HasStarted is always TRUE even there was a few bytes was written to Response.Body from Controller action.**

I thought Response Body has an internal buffer so context.Response.HasStarted must be FALSE unless the internal buffer was full.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't restart the response body. You can enable response buffering using a technique like this middleware does https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Buffering.